# How can I tell which MySQL process created a temporary file and if the temporary file is still in use?

Tags: mysql

We script commands (PERL normally) for MySQL (on Linux) which some times create temporary files that get left behind.  I am trying to write a monitoring script that can remove the files that have been orphaned.  I need to know not only that the file is no longer in use, which I can do through OS calls, but that MySQL is completely finished with it.

Can someone please tell me how I can interrogate MySQL via PERL or even just an SQL command (I can figure out the scripting aspect) to determine if MySQL is finished with a particular temporary table file or which process is currently using it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue a 'show processlist;' and focus on id,db,command,state, info columns

lets call the perl scripts PERL and the routine that cleans up CLEANUP (via cron or otherwise).

if you save in your perl script the output of 'select connection_id()' to a variable such as id #59, and insert this into an info-table with a timestamp, that is (id and timestamp) then sprinkle thru your PERL code the same thing every now and then.

CLEANUP can do date math to know that something out there is actively running. info-table will tell it that yes one of your PERL routines are active if the timestamps are recent

when PERL is done it can delete the rows with its connection id in that info table (as 1 idea).

this way the CLEANUP can know if anything PERL-like is active and take necessary steps to clean up

you could augment it by having another CONTROL-TABLE that PERL attempts to get a WRITE lock on (not that it necessarily will write to it but just an attempt). and CLEANUP can attempt to get a write lock on CONTROL-TABLE before it tries to cleanup. when PERL is done it releases the write lock. if it crashes the lock goes away. so that way CLEANUP is not relying entirely on the info-table with process id's from PERLs that are out there but rather like a semaphore. CLEANUP would get its lock on that table, do it's cleanup and block other PERLS from starting. you could have variations of exclusive table lock for CLEANUP and row level locks for PERLs so multiple PERLS could run at the same time

Comment: you can also have all your PERL routines utilize a certain user login and examine the "show processlist" output for the User column. Afterall, processid's are re-used, and only users=perl_script for example would be all those perl routines running

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have control over all of the scripts that cause these things to happen or the user IDs as the machine is in a test lab environment.  Some of these people are unlikely to take the suggestion on board properly.  I am trying to clean up after my colleagues who seem to like generating large temporary files.  Otherwise the connection id thing sounds like a very good idea.  I will have to introduce it to my team and see if we can make it a standard for inclusion and review in all future work.

Comment: In the end I used a combination of what you suggested. A periodic lsof on the mysqld process id, the show processlist you suggested and the long query log which tends to have the queries that cause these files in all of their glory.  The user column as you suggested is very useful too in connecting back to the person who indirectly created the file.